# OpenAI gym: Trouble installing Atari dependency (Mac OS X)

Tags: python, openai-gym

I'm new to OpenAI gym. I've successfully installed OpenAI gym on my Mac OS X (High Sierra 10.13.3) laptop and made a DQN for the CartPole game. I'm trying to install the Atari dependency to use MsPacman. I tried:

```
$ pip install gym[atari]
```

And get that Atari is successfully installed (I see atari_py in the same directory as gym and atari within the gym directory). But when I run the code I get:

```
raise error.DependencyNotInstalled("{}. (HINT: you can install Atari dependencies by running 'pip install gym[atari]'.)".format(e))
gym.error.DependencyNotInstalled: No module named atari_py. (HINT: you can install Atari dependencies by running 'pip install gym[atari]'.)
```

If I add:

```
import atari_py
```

to the source file, I get:

```
  File "dqn.py", line 9, in <module>
    import atari_py
ImportError: No module named atari_py
```

Edit: as per the documentation, I also tried

```
pip install -e '.[atari]'
```

And I get:

```
Directory '.' is not installable. File 'setup.py' not found.
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, this worked for me:

```
pip install 'gym[atari]'
```

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OSX Catalina
`pip3 install 'gym[atari]'`
worked for me

Answer (score 0):

From the [OpenAI Gym docs](https://github.com/openai/gym#atari) you can try

```
pip install -e '.[atari]'
```

Comment: I tried that too (edit to mention in original post) and I get:

Directory '.' is not installable. File 'setup.py' not found.